# Windows' remote desktop and licence trouble with softwares

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

When I use the remote desktop, there are some software (i.e. Matlab) that if are closed, is impossible to open them because when I try they say to me that there are some problems with the licence.

To overcome it I need to use Teamviewer and open it. Once is open, if it remains so I can use it without problems.

I found out that when I use the remote desktop, for a second I can see that at the logon of the user, it logs as "Other user" even if I put the name of my account and  the password.

I know that this is due to Windows, not the licence of any program. Is it possible to solve? Why does it say that is logging "Other user"? It's me but not physically in front of my computer.

I use Win10 Pro

Comment: Try [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/859213/18736).

Comment: Doesn't work. Still logs as "Other User". Teamviewer, a part that if I use it too much blocks me, is toooooo slow compared with remote desktop

Comment: Try in *Control Panel > System and Security > System > Remote settings*, to set "Allow connections only from computers running Remote Desktop with Network Level Authentication(more secure)".

Comment: Already checked but inside "Select Users..." the field is empty. Should I put "Other User" as account? Because mine has already access

Comment: I thought the idea is to logon as yourself. Have you verified what account you are logging at? One way to find that is via CMD entering the `whoami` command.

Comment: It's my correct account as it is supposed to be `Full computer name/user name`. But when I launch the remote desktop, at the logon says: "Other user". I don't know why

Comment: I don't know why either, but is it important when the logon is correct?

Comment: It seam so, or at least is what I think because if I close for example Matlab and I try to reopen it using the Microsoft Remote Desktop, an error message for the licence appears while with Teamviewer everything works correctly because in that case the remote desktop is not passing through the Microsoft RD and so when I log in, Windows know that is like I'm in front my computer. It does not figure that I'm with a remote software

Answer (score 0):

I did some research, and it seems that this is normal behavior for RDP
if you leave your PC logged-in.

When you remote in, it's a 'different user' even if it's the same credentials.

When a user is logged in, and then you remote desktop in as as the same user,
you are logged-in as "Other User" instead. You will find yourself logged into
a brand new session with nothing open.

This was always so. I have found references for it from as far as
[2009](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=50444).

It seems that the solution is simply to ensure a logout before doing remote desktop.
Try it and see if this solves the problem.

Comment: Tried but still doesn't work. I signed out with Teamviewer and logged in with the remote desktop. For a second "Other user" appeared, then changed in the true name of my account but still when I try yo open some programs, they give me the licence error. So there's no way to solve this thing. Changing something in some register or something else

Comment: I wonder what do these programs check that doesn't work with RDP. It might be the expanded user-name after logon which might be different. One last try (with not much chance for success): Reboot the computer (which will terminate TeamViewer), then do RDP as the first login after the reboot.

Comment: Nope, still not working. If can help, when I try to open Matlab it says "Matlab cannot be started through Terminal Services". Even after the reboot, when I log it with RDP I still see "Other user" and then changes name into my name. I found [https://serverfault.com/questions/455651/how-to-prevent-the-other-user-from-appearing-on-the-logon-screen-of-a-server] but I'm not sure that is doing what I need. I don't care if "Other user" appears or not. I just need that Windows thinks that I'm actually in front my computer.

Comment: I checked, and it seems that this limitation is on purpose, as Matlab limits usage to one user only. A workaround that was suggested is to locate the Matlab installation folder, maybe something similar to `C:\MATLAB6p5\bin\win32`, and create there an empty file called `wtsapi32.dll`.

Comment: Nothing. Still doesn't work

Comment: Matlab is simply refusing to work under Terminal Services and this is by design. You may try [Matlab Support](https://www.mathworks.com/support.html) or Sales, since this seems like a licensing issue - you are not licensed to run under Terminal Services.